# Selenium opens a blank page in chrome 84, works fine in 83

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir

I have the following code that works fine in chrome 83:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

@invitation = Invitation.last

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
driver.manage.window.resize_to(*@invitation.dimensions)
driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 10
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 
driver.navigate.to invitation_image_url(@invitation.id, auth_token: @invitation.signed_id)

puts driver.page_source
```

Now, when I update to chrome 84 the puts returns a blank page instead of the right one:

```
"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"
```

Why does it happen and how do i make it work in chrome 84?

Comment: Invitation is the class you created?

Comment: Can you give me the url?

Comment: This problem seems to be a problem in the driver, Ruby Selenium Binding people check the watir section, so I have added that tag.

Answer (score 0):

When you update chrome browser version you should use exact chromedriver version according to that browser version
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. in this link you can download chromdwriver exe based on browser version(after changing drivers please refresh project and run it)

Comment: I updated the chromedriver too, driver.capabilities returns that both browser_version and chromedriverversion are on 84.0.4147.30, problem still persists